# I have a Range input in order to change the color, but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, range, frontend

THis is my JS code, I wil laslo include my Git, and thank you so much for your time. 
https://github.com/bohorquez866/Rest-dish

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
 slider.oniput = () => {
 document.body.style.background = `linear-gradient(90deg, #2b22e43 ${slider.value}%,
     #2b2e43 ${silider.value}%, #ffffff ${silider.value}.1%, #ffffff ${slider.value}100%)`
}
```

Comment: Quick sanity check: Does your actual code include the misspelled `oniput` event handler, or is that typo only in the question you've written here?

Comment: I have it like that in both...

Comment: @apsillers [it sure does](https://github.com/bohorquez866/Rest-dish/blob/master/index.js#L2)

Comment: also `silider.value` should be `slider.value`

Comment: @JesúsBohorquez have a look at my answer.

Comment: Are you still having issues?

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of issues with your code as mentioned in the comments:

- A typo in the `slider.oniput` handler, it should be `slider.oninput`
- Typo(s) in the `document.body.style.background` string where you used `silider` instead of `slider`
- Typo in the `HEX` value for one of your colors `#2b22e43`, it should be `#2b22e4`

Here's a fixed example:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");

slider.oninput = () => {
  var currValue = slider.value;
  document.body.style.background = `linear-gradient(90deg, #2b22e4 ${currValue}%, #2b2e43 ${currValue}%, #ffffff ${currValue}.1%, #ffffff ${currValue}%)`;
};
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="range" id="slider" name="volume" min="0" max="11" />
  <label for="slider">slider</label>
</div>
```

Not sure if this is the effect that you're looking for, but it works. Feel free to tweak it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Is a syntax error, it's not slider.oniput is slider.oninput, you miss one N, and you write silider.value in the ${}.

Code edit below.

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
 slider.oninput = () => {
     document.body.style.background = `linear-gradient(90deg, #2b22e43 ${slider.value}%,
         #2b2e43 ${slider.value}%, #ffffff ${slider.value}.1%, #ffffff ${slider.value}100%)`
 }
```

Comment: Did you get...?

Comment: Yes, it wokrs now, but i have anotherp roblem now xD